# How to prove that a k-linear mapping is differentiable?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm reading [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521551145), page 64. My question is related to proposition 2.7.6. How do we prove that the function $T$ is differentiable?

[image]

Proposition 2.2.9 states that for a function to be differentiable at a point, all of its component functions must also be differentiable. Corollary 2.4.3. just states that the sum of two diff. functions is also a diff. function.

From what I understood, the author is stating that $T(a_1,...,a_k)=\sum_{j_1,...,j_k}\lambda_{j_1}(1)\cdots\lambda_{j_k}(k)T(e_{j_1},...,e_{j_k})$

But I'm stuck here...

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: is it because we can further expand $T$ as $T(a_1,...,a_k)=\sum_{j_1,...,j_k}\sum_{l=1}^{p}\lambda_{j_1}(1)\cdots\lambda_{j_k}(k)A_{j_1,...,j_k}^{l}b_l$, where $T(e_{j_1},...,e_{j_k})=\sum_l A_{j_1,...,j_k}^{l}b_l$, and so T is a polynomial in the components of $(a_1,...,a_k)$?

Answer (score 0):

I will do this from scratch, assuming $T$ is bilinear. The generalization to $p$ factors should be straightforward.

Take $(s_1,s_2)\in \mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n$ such that $\left \| s_i \right \|=1;\ i=1,2. $

Then, $s_i=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}e_k\ $ with $\vert a_{ik}\vert \le 1$ and

$T(s_1,s_2)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{1j}a_{2k}T(e_{j},e_{k})$ nd an application of the triangle inequality shows that

$\left \| T(s_1,s_2) \right \|\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left \| T(e_{j},e_{k}) \right \|$ so $T$ is bounded by some $M\ge 0$

Now,

$\tag1 T((s_1,s_2)+(h_1,h_2))=T(s_1+h_1,s_2+h_2)=T(s_1,s_2)+T(h_1,h_2)+T(s_1,h_2)+T(h_1,s_2)$

so that

$\tag2 T((s_1,s_2)+(h_1,h_2))-T(s_1,s_2)-(T(h_1,s_2)+T(s_1,h_2))=T(h_1,h_2)$.

Finally, we compute

$\tag3 \left \| \frac{T(h_1,h_2)}{h} \right \|\le M\frac{\left \| h_1 \right \|\left \| h_2 \right \|}{\left \| h \right \|}\le M\left \| h_2 \right \|$

and then letting $\left \| h \right \|\to 0$, we conclude that $DT(s_1,s_2)(h_1,h_2)=T(h_1,s_2)+T(s_1,h_2))$.

Comment: This argument works for a linear map. But the OP was asking about a _multilinear_ one.

Comment: @JackLee Could you help me? ;)

Comment: @Jack Lee: Why doesn't the result follow now by a simple induction?

Comment: @Chilango: It might. But it's not completely clear what you would apply the inductive hypothesis to if $T$ is $(k+1)$-multilinear. There's definitely something to prove.

Comment: in fact, the multilinearity of $T$ implies that  $T(a_1,\cdots, a_k)=T(a_1,0\cdots,0)+T(0,a_2,\cdots,0)+\cdots +T(0,\cdots,a_k)$, and each of the terms on the RHS may be handled by the argument in my answer.

Comment: Chilango, I don't understand why that last edit is true... 
Isn't multilinearity supposed to be $T(\alpha a+b,c)=\alpha T(a,c)+T(b,c)$?

@JackLee Chilango forgot to tag you.

Comment: The OP (@Anoldmaninthesea.) is right -- multilinearity does not imply $T(a_1,\dots,a_k) = T(a_1,0,\dots,0) + \dots + T(0,\dots,a_k)$. For example, the dot product on $\mathbb R^n$ is bilinear, but it does not satisfy $a_1\cdot a_2 = a_1\cdot 0 + 0\cdot a_2$.

Comment: True. I will do it from scratch and post my edit-